# whenever the page loads i want to partially collapse the parent resources in fullcalender.io-Timeline View

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, fullcalendar, salesforce-lightning

We are using fullcalender- Timeline View  with multiple parent resources and childs. I'm trying to implement a feature whenever the view loads , I want to collapse all parent resources except few.

I used this code in js file
`resourcesInitiallyExpanded : false`, if i add this line to below code all parent groups are collapsing

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'today prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'resourceTimelineDay,resourceTimelineWeek'
    },
    aspectRatio: 1.6,
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
    resourceGroupField: 'building',
    resources: [
      { id: 'a', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium A' },
      { id: 'b', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium B' },
      { id: 'c', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium C' },
      { id: 'd', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium D' },
      { id: 'e', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium E' },
      { id: 'f', building: '460 Bryant', title: 'Auditorium F' },
      { id: 'g', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium G' },
      { id: 'h', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium H' },
      { id: 'i', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium I' },
      { id: 'j', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium J' },
      { id: 'k', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium K' },
      { id: 'l', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium L' },
      { id: 'm', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium M' },
      { id: 'n', building: '564 Pacific', title: 'Auditorium N' },
      { id: 'o', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium O' },
      { id: 'p', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium P' },
      { id: 'q', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium Q' },
      { id: 'r', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium R' },
      { id: 's', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium S' },
      { id: 't', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium T' },
      { id: 'u', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium U' },
      { id: 'v', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium V' },
      { id: 'w', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium W' },
      { id: 'x', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium X' },
      { id: 'y', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium Y' },
      { id: 'z', building: '101 Main St', title: 'Auditorium Z' }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

using above snippet the current view looks like the photo attached below

reference: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline-resourceGroupField-demo

[[image]]

Any suggestions on how to achieve what is in the below picture?
[image]

Comment: Please don't use caps like this, it's considered shouting and it's rude. Also please show us your code. without it we can't give you a good answer to why it's not working.

Comment: And please remember that Java and JavaScript are not the same language and the terms cannot be used interchangeably.

Comment: Unfortunately what you're asking for isn't currently possible in any version of fullCalendar. I suggest you [request a feature](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) if you would like this, and if you are able, consider contributing the necessary code yourself to speed things up.